# Slow network copy between iMac and MacBook Air

Tags: wifi, macbook-pro, imac, airport

I am getting a maximum lousy 1,5 MB copy speed between two Macs on my local network. My hardware is:

- iMac6,1 (2006)
- AirPort Express A1264 (2008)
- MacBook Air3,2 (2010)

The AirPort and the MacBook are both 802.11n-compliant according to my findings, but the iMac says "802.11a/b/g (draft-n disabled by default)".

1. Is 2MB/s the best I can expect with the current hardware?
2. Is "draft-n" something I can "enable" on the iMac? If so, how?
3. What speeds are the best possible between units that are all 802.11n?

Answer (score 1):

1) I do not think so.

2) You need **Apple Extreme 802.11n Enabler for Mac**, more Information is [How to tell if 802.11n-enabling software is installed](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2447) or an OSX Update. See [HT2447](https://discussions.apple.com/article/HT2447).

Comment: "enter link description here"

Comment: @dor: Using the "How to tell" method, it says "/n" on the end on the iMac. What next?